# Await / async - async method runs in Main Thread

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, task, async-await

I just started to learn Async/Await, and I've got a problem. There is a WinForms App with 2 buttons and permanently running status-bar on it. When pressing first button - everithing is fine - cicle running in another thread and UI doesn't freeze. When pressing second - cicle running in Main Thread, so UI freeze. I just can't get it! Why? For me this methods look almost the same. Btw sry my bad english.

```
 Public Class Form1
    'Async - Create Task from Sync Method
    Private Async Sub btn_async_from_sync_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_async_from_sync.Click
        Dim tsk As New Task(Of Integer)(AddressOf func_for_task)
        tsk.Start()
        Dim val As Integer = Await tsk
        MsgBox(val)
    End Sub
    Private Function func_for_task() As Integer
        Dim val As Integer
        For i = 1 To 999999999
            val += 1
        Next
        Return val
    End Function
    'Async - Use existing Task - Async Method
    Private Async Sub btn_async_use_task_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_async_use_task.Click
        Dim tsk As Task(Of Integer) = func_for_task_async()
        Dim val As Integer = Await tsk
        MsgBox(val)
    End Sub
    Private Async Function func_for_task_async() As Task(Of Integer)
        Dim val As Integer
        For i = 1 To 999999999
            val += 1
        Next
        Return val
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The key thing to know that when using Async/Await, everything will not always run on a background thread, especially in the case of gui apps.  Very often, the system will not just to queue the task on the UI message pump, and will run on the UI thread if the scheduler thinks it is beneficial to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ignore compiler warnings. In this case, the compiler will warn you that your `async` method does not use `await`, and therefore will run synchronously.

In your case, you can use `Task.Run` to execute `func_for_task` on a background thread, and `await` it from your click event handler.

For more info, see the [`async`/`await` intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Tnx a lot, man!! Now i got the basic idea of Await/Async, tnx to your great article! I can just recommend it to all begginers.